# How to find a conformal mapping which maps the region between |z + 3| < √ 10 and |z − 2| < √ 5 onto the interior of the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Yesterday I spent some time trying to find a conformal mapping which maps the region between |z + 3| <
√10 and |z − 2| <
√5
onto the interior of the first quadrant.

I started with determining the two intersection points of the two boundary circles, and found that they are i and - i. Next I constructed the Möbius transformation (z - i) / (z+i) which, I thought, would map the two boundary circles to two straight lines through the origin.

Furthermore I calculated the images of -3 + sqr(10) and 2 - sqr(5). The results were some real multiples of -2 + i and -3 - i. The lines through the origin and those two points didn't seem perpendicular, but the angle between them was hard to determine. Therefore I didn't know how to modify my Möbius transformation inte a conformal mapping which would satisfy the specified requirement.

My way out of the dilemma was to cheat and look at a published solution. There I saw that I had to square the Möbius transformation to make the image lines perpendicular and finally multiply everything by an appropriate constant to turn the lines to the desired position.

What I don't understand is how you could come up with the idea of squaring the Möbius transformation if you didn't have access to a published solution. If you could somehow realise that the original angle between the image lines is 45 degrees, then it would be natural to use the square function to get a 90 degree angle instead, but it doesn't seem obvious at all that the original angle is precisely 45 degrees and not for instance 43.7 degrees or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it draw your diagram. The angle at which your two circles meet at $i$   or $(0,1)$   is the angle between the tangent lines $y = 1-3x$   and $y = 1 + 2x.$  Or between vectors $(-1,3)$   and $(1,2)$

Meanwhile, the derivative of Moebius transformation $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  is simply $\frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2}.$  So, other than the point it sends to infinity, it preserves angles.

[image]

Comment: Nice diagram! Is the angle between the mentioned vectors 45 degrees?