# Is it possible to explain geometrically why $\arctan (1/2) +\arctan (1/3) = 45$ degrees?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, proof-without-words

$\arctan(1/2)$ seems to be some strange, irrational angle, and the same goes for $\arctan(1/3)$, but those two angles seem to sum up to $45$ degrees. This seems like a mystery to me even though I can derive the result algebraically as follows, by using the summation formula for the tangent function.

$\tan\big(\arctan(1/2)+\arctan (1/3)\big)=\dfrac{5/6}{1 - 1/6}=1\,.$

Can someone come up with a geometric explanation?

A remark: I started thinking about the described arctan puzzle while I was trying to solve a problem in complex analysis, namely this one:

[How to find a conformal mapping which maps the region between |z + 3| < √ 10 and |z − 2| < √ 5 onto the interior of the first quadrant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4752538/800134)

Comment: This is the gist of the well-known "Three Squares Problem" popularized by Martin Gardner. Numberphile has [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5evLoL0xwg) about it; my Trigonography site has [a picture proof](https://trigonography.com/?p=176). I'm *pretty sure* I've seen it mentioned here, but I can't seem to find any instances after a cursory search.

Comment: I like the approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254427/11619) a lot. The formula $$\arctan1+\arctan2+\arctan3=\pi$$ is equivalent to yours, and easier to visualize!

Comment: @Blue Did you have in mind the same picture I had (see the link)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's good, too. See [my own link](https://trigonography.com/?p=176).

Comment: Misread, sorry.

Comment: The simplest algebraic reason is $(2+i)(3+i)=5 (1 + i)$.

Comment: @lhf I'm interested in any special property of the Gaussian integers

Comment: Are we talking about spins here?

Comment: @qwr, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula

Comment: FYI: I found a Math.SE question about the [$3$-squares puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605964/409) (and showing [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1606045/409)). Perhaps of interest: [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800600/409) asking about extending the $3$-squares puzzle to $n$ squares.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are many good geometric renderings; my favorite invokes the familiar Red Cross symbol. This symbol consists of a central square block sharing each of its edges with an additional congruent block. We superpose right triangle $ABC$ and label some additional vertices $D,E,F$ as shown below.

[image]

$\triangle \space ACD$ and $CBE$ are right triangles with congruent legs, so congruent triangles by SAS; thus their hypotenuses which are also legs of right $\triangle ABC$ are congruent. So the acute angle $BAC$ measures $45°$. But the component of that angle within right $\triangle ACD$ measures $\arctan(1/2)$ and the remaining component within right $\triangle ABF$ measures $\arctan(1/3)$. Thereby $\arctan(1/2)+\arctan(1/3)=45°$.

Comment: When only the best will do...Nice!

Comment: @qwr I don't think that they are 30-60-90 triangles.They are two triangles with an angle $\arctan(1/2)$.

Comment: Yes you're right. I misinterpreted the diagram

Comment: Nice. I foresee a few calculus students working this out when reviewing trig functions :-)

Answer (score 8):

Let us take $\triangle ABC$ with $AB=3, BC=4, CA=5, \angle B = 90^\circ$. Let the angle bisectors $AI, BI, CI$ meet at incenter $I$. From $I$ drop perpendiculars $ID,IE,IF$ onto the sides.
The inradius is $ID=IE=IF=1$. Clearly $BFID$ is a square, so $BF=BD=1$, $AF=AE=2$, $CD=CE=3$. This leads to the angles as in the following diagram.

[image]

Thus $\frac{A}{2}=\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{C}{2}=\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3}$. But $A+C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ means
$$\frac{A}{2}+\frac{C}{2}=\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2}+\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
As a bonus, adding the six angles formed at the incenter gives
$$2\tan^{-1} 1 + 2\tan^{-1} 2 +2\tan^{-1} 3 =2\pi$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan^{-1} 1 + \tan^{-1} 2 +\tan^{-1} 3 =\pi$$

Similar dissections of other right triangles $\{(5,12,13),$ $(7,24,25), \ldots\}$ will give new identities involving $\tan^{-1} (\text{rational number})$.

Comment: For every Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ with $c$ as hypotenuse: $\arctan(\frac{c-a+b}{c+a+b})+\arctan(\frac{c+a-b}{c+a+b})=45°$. $(3,4,5)\implies\arctan(1/2)+\arctan(1/3)$, $(5,12,13)\implies\arctan(1/5)+\arctan(2/3)$.

Answer (score 6):

Just a comment on the beautiful answer of @Oscar Lanzi:, if we add four strips of width $1$ and length $x$ to a square of side $1$, we get again a cross with an inscribed square, and the equality

$$\arctan \frac{1}{2x + 1} + \arctan\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$\bf{Added:}$  In the picture below, the yellow segments  have length $1$, the light blue have length $x$.

[image: cross_angle]

$\bf{Added:}$ With the same method, with some care, we can prove the addition formula for the tangent. Indeed, consider two rectangles with sides, $a$, $b$ , and two with sides $t a$, $t b$.  (in the picture below,  sides $2,5$ and $4$, $10 $) .  Arrange them so we from their diagonals we get a rectangle with the ratio of the sides $t$. Then we get the formula

$$\arctan \frac{a}{b} + \arctan\frac{t b - a}{t a + b} = \arctan t$$

[image: tangent of sums]

In our [case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ArcTan%5B2%2F5%5D%20%2B%20ArcTan%5B8%2F9%5D-%20ArcTan%5B2%5D)

$$\arctan\frac{2}{5} + \arctan\frac{8}{9} = \arctan 2$$

Note: If we start from an arbitrary symmetric cross we might not get a rectangle, but only a parallelogram, so we modified the approach a bit. In general, to get a cross that produces a rotated rectangle, start with a container rectangle and intersect its sides with a central circle.

Comment: Can you include a diagram to emphasize the geometry?

Comment: @qwr: Just added one, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: what program did you use? geogebra? it's very hard for me to see

Comment: @qwr: yes, it is geogebra, I should probably share the file somewhere.  Can you click on the image, view, and then enlarge?  I reduced the size due to bandwidth concerns of some people.

Comment: yes I enlarge the image, it's just the colors. I can take a stab at making a diagram tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

With $0 < a < b,$

$$   \arctan \frac{a}{b}  + \arctan \frac{-a+b}{a+b}  =  \frac{\pi}{4}  $$

as vectors, in order to add  the angles, we need to ask the angle between vectors $v=(-1,2)$  and $w=(1,3).$  This is what I was doing in answering your previous question.

$$ \cos \theta = \frac{v \cdot w}{|v| \; |w|}  =  \frac{5}{ \sqrt 5 \; \sqrt{10}} = \frac{5}{\sqrt{50}} $$

so
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{5}{5 \sqrt 2}  = \frac{1}{ \sqrt 2}   $$

We get something similar with $v=(-1,5)$  and $w=(2,3).$

Or with $v=(2,5)$  and $w=(-3,7).$

Or with any integers $0 < a < b,$  vectors $v=(a,b)$  and $w=(a-b,a+b).$

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the variety of many fine geometrical answers, express the measures of the following three angles in terms of arctangent and compare the results:

$$ \angle CAD, \angle DAB, \angle CAB $$

[image: Equilateral right triangle sides sqrt(10)]